# How can I create and execute a cell in Jupyter Notebook server from a separate process (e.g., an editor, vim)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, vim, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I want to call an api on a running jupyter notebook to create or edit an existing cell, and to run it. When this is done, the browser page should also update, to show both the contents of the cell, and the output.

The intended use case for this api is a plugin for the vim editor that will take highlighted lines and execute them. The motivation for using jupyter notebook is that will allow visualization of plots and images using matplotlib, even though both vim and the notebook will be running on a remote server. The user would have a browser page open to the notebook, and separately a terminal open potentially that is ssh'ed to the machine and editing python code.

VSCode does exactly this in its python interactive mode, but I prefer to use the vim editor natively than switch to vscode simply to be able to do this.

Answer (score 3):

There are several plugins being actively developed for this, and without having used them, it seems only [vimpyter](https://github.com/szymonmaszke/vimpyter) interacts with jupyter on the browser. Others like [jupyter-vim](https://github.com/wmvanvliet/jupyter-vim) and [vim-ipython](https://github.com/ivanov/vim-ipython) open the notebook inside a vim buffer.

If you can live without inline plots I find confortable having a [neoterm](https://github.com/kassio/neoterm) terminal buffer where I can send lines to and from IPython.

Comment: I currently use neoterm as well, and I have a command to send selected lines to the ipython running in terminal and execute it. However, what I really want is a way to see plots and outputs in the browser when I am working on a remote machine. I will try vimpyter and see if it does it. Though, it says I'll have to reload, which is not quite what I want. 

Another idea was to use iterm2 to display images in the terminal but the inline image functionality does not work inside neoterm.

Answer (score 1):

There's a relatively new nvim plugin called [Jupynium](https://github.com/kiyoon/jupynium.nvim) that does something like this.

It works via Selenium, so you edit your code inside vim and it syncs the cell input and execution output to a live browser running the notebook.

Currently, I think this is the closest you can get to working with jupyter notebooks "inside" vim

Answer (score 0):

You could use vscode's built in jupyter notebook support to convert the notebook into a python file

Answer (score -1):

this is not an exact answer, but I've written a couple Jupyter plugins that may be helpful to you in this endeavor, [JupyterGraffiti](https://github.com/willkessler/jupytergraffiti) and [JupyterTerminals](https://github.com/willkessler/jupyterterminals). Graffiti has an API you can call to execute some of its functions, and it supports inline terminals you can control. JupyterTerminals provides only those inline terminals, but also has buttons you can add to control them.  You could start and run vim inside these terminals. (If it's useful an API could be added to the JupyterTerminals plugin like Graffiti has.)

[image]